# Generating SSRS and converting into PDF automatically

Tags: vb.net

I want to automatically convert my SSRS to pdf and store to a location on my hard drive (say C:\My Reports)
How can this target be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the reporting services web service. A nice post where this is done is: http://geekswithblogs.net/bsherwin/archive/2007/04/29/112094.aspx

```
Dim result() As Byte
Dim report As String = "/Sample Reports/Sales Order Detail"
Dim format As String = "PDF"
Dim historyid As String = Nothing
Dim devinfo As String = ""
Dim credentials() As SQLRS.DataSourceCredentials = Nothing
Dim showhide As String = Nothing
Dim encoding As String
Dim mimetype As String
Dim warnings() As SQLRS.Warning = Nothing
Dim reporthistoryparams As SQLRS.ParameterValue() = Nothing
Dim streamid() As String = Nothing
Dim sh As New SQLRS.SessionHeader
ws.SessionHeaderValue = sh 
Next, get the result from the web service:

result = ws.Render(report, format, historyid, devinfo, parameters, _
            credentials, showhide, encoding, mimetype, reporthistoryparams, _
            warnings, streamid)

Dim stream As FileStream = File.Create("C:\My Reports\report.pdf", results.Length)
stream.Write(results, 0, results.Length)
stream.Close()
```

Comment: I updated my answer, just write the result to file instead of showing it in the browser.

Comment: Thanks again but where does it get info which report to be written as PDF?

Comment: Dim report As String = "/Sample Reports/Sales Order Detail"

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Can I just put it in the Button on form that contains my reportviewer?   What do you mean by       just write the result to file instead of showing it in the browser

Comment: Yes, but as stated in the linked blog post you first have to create a web reference to the reporting services web service but then you can put the code above in a button. What I meant with storing the result in a file was just a clarification of the last three lines in the code sample.